# Count consecutive days and include column that indicates the start date of count

Tags: r

```
columnames=c("UserId","ItemName","Date","MonthTake","YearTaken")

row1=c("1" , "Apple"  ,      "8/30/2019"   , "8"  , "2019")
row2=c("1" , "Apple"  ,      "8/31/2019"   , "8"  , "2019")
row3=c("1" , "Apple"  ,      "9/1/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")
row4=c("1" , "Apple"  ,      "9/2/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")
row5=c("1" , "Banana" ,      "9/3/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")
row6=c("1" , "Banana" ,      "9/4/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")
row7=c("2" , "Banana" ,      "9/3/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")
row8=c("2" , "Banana" ,      "9/4/2019"    , "9"  , "2019")

d<-rbind(columnames,row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7,row8)
d1<-as.data.frame(d)

header.true <- function(d1) {
  names(d1) <- as.character(unlist(d1[1,]))
  d1[-1,]
}
d1<-header.true(d1)






  UserID         ItemName     Date        MonthTaken   YearTaken 
   1             Apple        8/30/219     8            2019
   1             Apple        8/31/219     8            2019
   1             Apple        9/1/219      9            2019
   1             Apple        9/2/219      9            2019
   1             Banana       9/3/219      9            2019
   1             Banana       9/4/219      9            2019
   2             Banana       9/3/219      9            2019
   2             Banana       9/4/219      9            2019



  data1%>%
        group_by(UserID,ItemName,MonthTaken,YearTaken, days=c(0,cumsum(diff(Date)!=1)))%>%
        summarise(Date=n())%>%
        select(-days)
```

I am using the above code and I am able to have the consecutive days per user id , per Item Name, on the Month and year the item was used.

Like this:

```
UserID               ItemName     Date               MonthTaken   YearTaken 
       1             Apple        2                      8            2019

       1             Apple        2                      9            2019

       1             Banana       2                      9            2019

       2             Banana       2                      9            2019
```

I want to remove the Month and Year groupings, but somehow include the starting date of the count instead.  The goal is that if someone took something on 8/31/2019 and 9/1/2019, the Consecutive count is 2 starting in August, instead of 1 for August and 1 for September.

End goal like this :

```
  UserID         ItemName     StartDate     ConsecutiveDays 
   1             Apple        8/30/219        4
   1             Banana       9/3/219         2
   2             Banana       9/3/219         2
```

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(data1)` in your question? As it is right now the question isn't reproducible.

Comment: I tried to add in additional code that generates the data frame example i created. I am making this up for this example as my data can not be shared.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `Date` is in `Date` format:

```
d1$Date <- as.Date(d1$Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Adapting what you have, would not `group_by` `MonthTaken` or `YearTaken`, and add `StartDate` to `summarise`:

```
d1 %>%
  arrange(UserID, ItemName, Date) %>%
  group_by(UserID, ItemName, days = c(0, cumsum(diff(Date) != 1))) %>%
  summarise(ConsecutiveDays=n(),
            StartDate = first(Date))%>%
  select(-days)
```

**Edit**: Added `arrange` to account for possibility of dates out of order. This needs to be sorted before `cumsum` in `group_by`.

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   UserID, ItemName [3]
  UserID ItemName ConsecutiveDays StartDate 
  <fct>  <fct>              <int> <date>    
1 1      Apple                  4 2019-08-30
2 1      Banana                 2 2019-09-03
3 2      Banana                 2 2019-09-03
```

Comment: So simple. So beautiful. Thank you so much Ben!

Comment: I was examining in detail the output (on the real data) and for some reason there are instances where this does not work. I have data points that are consecutive and are not counted . Any ideas why this is not working uniformly?

Comment: Can you share data on those examples where this happened? Would like to look into...

Comment: I am working with data that i can not actually share.   I started with 383912 rows and after running the code ended up with 182196 . So a lot of it is counting correctly. But the as an  example my first output is   two rows, of the same UserID with 1 consecutive day of Banana but the start day is 1/4/2016 and 1/5/2016. This should just be 2 days.

Comment: I wonder should the data be sorted first? or does that not matter

Comment: if the dates are out of order, that would make a difference - are the dates out of order?

Comment: Would add `arrange(UserID, ItemName, Date)` in the pipe first, I'll update the answer now - let me know if this works